# SQLAlchemy: enforce Soft Delete for a ForeignKeyConstraint

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, soft-delete

What is an elegant way to enforce the soft delete pattern with ForeignKeyConstraint?

As described in [SQLAlchemy 1.4](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html?highlight=execute_state%20is_column_load#sqlalchemy.orm.with_loader_criteria) and in this [example](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/extending_query/filter_public.html) we are enforcing the soft delete like this:

```
 @event.listens_for(Session, "do_orm_execute")
 def _enforce_soft_delete(execute_state):
     """Enforce soft delete."""
     if (
         not execute_state.is_column_load
         and not execute_state.is_relationship_load
         and not execute_state.execution_options.get("load_deleted", False)
     ):
         execute_state.statement = execute_state.statement.options(
             orm.with_loader_criteria(
                 SoftDelete,
                 lambda cls: cls.IsDeleted == false(),
                 include_aliases=True,
             )
         )
```

It works perfect, except for ForeignKeyConstraints.

```
class SoftDelete(object):
    """Mixin that identifies a class as having isDeleted flag for soft deletion."""

    IsDeleted = Column(Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)


class A(SoftDelete, Base):
    __tablename__ = "A"

    ExternalID = Column(
        BigInteger,
        ForeignKey(f"B.ID", name="FK_A_B"),
    )
```

If I have an Object B which is marked as deleted I can still create an object A with a reference to it. I know I can check this manually but I'm looking for a more sophisticated solution.

Other SO SQLAlchemy SoftDelete answers did not help: [Implementing a “soft delete” system using sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522391/implementing-a-soft-delete-system-using-sqlalchemy) and [SQLAlchemy association table with soft delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62831285/sqlalchemy-association-table-with-soft-delete)

Comment: I really don't know if there's a "sophisticated" solution. If the record exists in the table, from the data integrity perspective it's a valid reference. As you pointed out, a manual check might be the only option here. It doesn't mean you have to do it in the code, though. Have you considered using a database trigger?

Comment: Thanks @AndreFeijo, the trigger approach may be an alternative. But since we have no other triggers (yet) I prefer the `manual` in code check.

Comment: Which database are you using, by the way?

Comment: Local: MS SQL Server, for dev & prod Azure SQL Database, system running on a Azure WebApp.

Answer (score 0):

We finally came up w/ this solution which works like a charm and it can be used quiet generic:

```
def check_constraints(db_session, object):
    """Test hard deletion to benefit from foreign keys."""
    try:
        db_session.delete(object)
        db_session.flush()
        db_session.rollback()
    except Exception as ex:
        db_session.rollback()
        // handle your conflict here
        raise
```